# Autolayout and UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, autolayout

So I want to get rid of all “frames” in my code and completely switch to autolayout. But there is one case when I want the Y position of the view to be dependent on the `content offset` (`bounds.origin.y`) of a `UIScrollView`. What is the right way to do this using `auto layout`? One idea is to have a constant of the `NSLayoutConstraint` updated every time the `scrollview content offset` is changed, (but then what’s the point of using auto layout here?) so I was hoping there is better way to achieve that with “pure” `autolayout`.

I know that "`Autolayout` & `UIScrollView`” is frequently discussed here, so I want to stress that I do not want to use auto layout for `UIScrollView` subviews, I have a `UIView` with 2 subviews; a `UIScrollView` and a `UIView` objects, and I want to use auto layout to specify the relation between a `UIView` top coordinate and `UIScrollView` content offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can do this fairly easily. It's essentially just like you would do it with frames.

First you need to create your "variable" constraint and save it into a property.

You can do this in code...

```
self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.theView
attribute:
relatedBy:
toItem:
attribute:
multiplier:
constant:];
// set up the rest

[self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
```

or do it in Interface Builder by creating the constraint and then ctrl drag to the property. (Like with any other IBOutlet).

Then when the scrollView scrolls...

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = calculatedValueFromTheOffset;

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

This will then move the view just as if you had used frames but using auto layout constraints instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant here "One idea is to have a constant of the NSLayoutConstraint updated every time the scrollview content offset is changed". Actually, it's not "height" constraint, but rather "top y" constraint

Comment: OK, cool. Yeah that's exactly how you would do it. There isn't a way to link a constraint and the offset of a scrollView so it's not really possible to do it any other way. Sorry.